# Using numpy.fill with Numba 'nopython' mode

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to use numpy fill function to fill up values in an ndarray. I have this under a function using Numba and I get an attribute error. Here is an example of my code:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def computething(param1):
    x = np.sum(param1)
    x1 = np.zeros(10)
    x1.fill(x)
```

*Note this is only an example code.

And I get the following error:

```
UntypedAttributeError: Unknown attribute 'fill' of type array(float64, 1d, C)
```

How can this error be prevented? thank you!

Comment: side note: I don't think you should use `numba` for that function since your only using `numpy` function, no python there

Comment: What was the exact input? A simple array such as `[1,2,3]` worked fine

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work with nopython=True option turned on--with it turned off it works fine. The function has some additional Numba compatible functions that need this to be turned on to make the process faster. However, this is breaking only when using numpy fill function. The exact input is an array, which then is shrunk to a single number by doing the sum, and then filling the new array with that single value using numpy fill.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution that works is:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def computething(param1):
    x = np.sum(param1)
    x1 = np.zeros(10)
    x1[:] = x
```

The numpy fill function however still gives an attribute error when nopython=True is set. It works ok with nopython=False.